# Why do I get these errors C2134, C4430 etc, in VS with QT?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opengl

I have a task to do an OpenGL application in Visual Studio with the QT add-on.

I am trying to compile the code but I am having some errors. This is happening when I PROMOTE the WIDGET where I want to display the OpenGL stuff, to the class that i have created.

here are the errors:

```
Error   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  32  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   32  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   48  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'QTOpenGLVS' 48  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   49  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2227: left of '->setObjectName' must point to class/struct/union/generic type    49  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   53  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2227: left of '->sizePolicy' must point to class/struct/union/generic type   53  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2228: left of '.hasHeightForWidth' must have class/struct/union  53  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   54  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2227: left of '->setSizePolicy' must point to class/struct/union/generic type    54  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   56  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  32  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   32  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   48  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'QTOpenGLVS' 48  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   49  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2227: left of '->setObjectName' must point to class/struct/union/generic type    49  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   53  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2227: left of '->sizePolicy' must point to class/struct/union/generic type   53  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2228: left of '.hasHeightForWidth' must have class/struct/union  53  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   54  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2227: left of '->setSizePolicy' must point to class/struct/union/generic type    54  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   56  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  32  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   32  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   48  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'QTOpenGLVS' 48  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   49  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2227: left of '->setObjectName' must point to class/struct/union/generic type    49  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   53  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2227: left of '->sizePolicy' must point to class/struct/union/generic type   53  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2228: left of '.hasHeightForWidth' must have class/struct/union  53  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   54  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2227: left of '->setSizePolicy' must point to class/struct/union/generic type    54  1   QTOpenGLVS
Error   error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier   56  1   QTOpenGLVS
```

The classes that i have are the **main.cpp**, **qtopenglvs.cpp** and the header file: **qtopenglvs.h**

main.cpp:

```
#include "qtopenglvs.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "MyGlWindow.h"


void init(){

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTOpenGLVS w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

qtopenglvs.cpp

```
#include "qtopenglvs.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>

QTOpenGLVS::QTOpenGLVS(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

void QTOpenGLVS::initiliazeGL(){
    glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
}
void QTOpenGLVS::paintGL(){

}
void QTOpenGLVS::resizeGL(int w, int h){

}
```

qtopenglvs.h

```
#ifndef QTOPENGLVS_H
#define QTOPENGLVS_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_qtopenglvs.h"

class QTOpenGLVS : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QTOpenGLVS(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void initiliazeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);

private:
    Ui::QTOpenGLVSClass ui;
};

#endif // QTOPENGLVS_H
```

**EDITED**
ui_qtopenglvs.h:

```
/*******************************************************************************    *
** Form generated from reading UI file 'qtopenglvs.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.5.1
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_QTOPENGLVS_H
#define UI_QTOPENGLVS_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpacerItem>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include "qtopenglvs.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_QTOpenGLVSClass
{
public:
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QTOpenGLVS *widget;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer;
    QPushButton *pushButton;

void setupUi(QMainWindow *QTOpenGLVSClass)
{
    if (QTOpenGLVSClass->objectName().isEmpty())
        QTOpenGLVSClass->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("QTOpenGLVSClass"));
    QTOpenGLVSClass->resize(834, 552);
    centralWidget = new QWidget(QTOpenGLVSClass);
    centralWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));
    horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(centralWidget);
    horizontalLayout->setSpacing(6);
    horizontalLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
    horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("horizontalLayout"));
    widget = new QTOpenGLVS(centralWidget);
    widget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("widget"));
    QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(widget->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
    widget->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);

    horizontalLayout->addWidget(widget);

    verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    verticalLayout->setSpacing(6);
    verticalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("verticalLayout"));
    verticalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer);

    pushButton = new QPushButton(centralWidget);
    pushButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));

    verticalLayout->addWidget(pushButton);


    horizontalLayout->addLayout(verticalLayout);

    QTOpenGLVSClass->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    retranslateUi(QTOpenGLVSClass);
    QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), QTOpenGLVSClass, SLOT(close()));

    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(QTOpenGLVSClass);
} // setupUi

void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *QTOpenGLVSClass)
{
    QTOpenGLVSClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("QTOpenGLVSClass", "QTOpenGLVS", 0));
    pushButton->setText(QApplication::translate("QTOpenGLVSClass", "Quit", 0));
} // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
   class QTOpenGLVSClass: public Ui_QTOpenGLVSClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_QTOPENGLVS_H
```

Answer (score 0):

The include for `QWidget` is missing, thus it is not recognized in `qtopenglvs.h`.

Add

```
#include <QWidget>
```

to the `qtopenglvs.h` header.

It looks as if you stripped down the code for the question, because there might be another problem with `widget`, which is not present here.

**Edit:**
The code contains a cyclic dependency (include B.h in A.h and A.h in B.h) which is not going to work. I do not exactly know what you want to achieve, since `setupUi` is called from the constructor and creates a new `QTOpenGLVS` (which again calls the constructor) which will end in an infinite recursion. At the moment it looks as if every `QTOpenGLVS` should have a `QTOpenGLVS` as child?

Comment: I added it but it still is showing me the same errors :(

Comment: I really don't know what's wrong with it. When I PROMOTE the Widget with this class I get the errors, if I DEMOTE it than its all right... so the  bug is somewhere in these classes

Comment: Could also be a problem in `ui_qtopenglvs.h`. Am I right that the error happens in the constructor declaration line?

Comment: Wow, i checked the errors now and yes it is in the declarations. The first error starts here; QTOpenGLVS *widget;

Comment: This is (as already said in the answer) not part of the code you posted. So how should we help you?

Comment: I have Edited now the post and added ui_qtopenglvs.h, Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: I am a beginner in C++, OpenGL and QT. I now removed the setupUI and also the PRIVATE part in qtopenglvs.h..... it still is showing me the same errors

Comment: **This is wrong advice**. First of all, you should never have an include of the form `#include <QtModule/foo.h>` - the inclusion of the Qt module prefix masks wrong configuration of the project. If you have to do it to get it to compile, it still won't link. Secondly, the header you're supposed to use is `QWidget`, **not** `qwidget.h`. **The proper include line is `#include <QWidget>`** or simply `#include <QtWidgets>` so that you don't need to enumerate everything.

Comment: @KubaOber The include path only depends on the configured include directory. And how could the include path influence linking? The comment might paetially be correct when using qtcreator and a pro configuration, but this question is tagged with visual Studio. Note that even the auto-generated file contains the module names.

Comment: You're not setting up any include paths manually in Visual Studio either. They are already set up by the Qt add-in, or by `qmake` that generated your `.vsproj` file. The include paths don't influence linking, but the wrong paths (missing the modules you use) have a workaround of prepending module to the included file name. You'd do that to get the source to compile, but the project wouldn't link. The auto-generated file is not an example of how you should write your own code. **TL;DR: If your code has anything but `#include <QFoo>` or `#include <QtModule>` for includes, it's wrong.**

Comment: When it comes to moc-generated files, there are some scenarios where the moc output might need to pull a header from a given module even if that module is not configured in the project, and thus not linked to the executable. It wouldn't be in the include path either, then - but the root path is. Qt tries very hard not to introduce any diagnostics from within its own headers and generated files, even in slightly misconfigured builds. People have a tendency of trying to modify those to fix things, instead of fixing the source of the problem: wrong project configuration or out-of-date makefiles.

Comment: @KubaOber I changed the path in the answer because I see your point why it is not the best advice to give here since it could mask configuration problems. Still, I don't think the answer was wrong since the path will work in any qt project as long as the project is configured correctly.

Comment: Qt does not guarantee the existence of `qwidget.h`. The API is defined as `QWidget`. So far, `QWidget` simply redirects to `qwidget.h`, but that's an implementation detail. From user's POV, `qwidget.h` doesn't exist. Your answer not only advocated the unnecessary use of the module prefix, but also advocated the use of the wrong include file. Now it's correct, of course.